# How to get viewBox of SVG to use the entire available space?

Tags: reactjs, svg

My viewBox, why does ist not "fill" the entire svg. In this (react-based) example I have a div with 200px width and 150px height. Within this div, there is a svg with the same dimensions. This svg has a viewBox of "0 0 100 100". Inside the svg, there is a rectangle that should occupy the entire viewBox (= the entire svg), but it doesn't. Strangely, the rectangle is smaller than the svg despite its dimensions 0, 0, 100, 100.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated!

styles.css

```
test-component-div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.test-component-svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

TestComponent.tsx

```ts
import './styles.css';
import React from 'react';

const TestComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="test-component-div">
      <svg className="test-component-svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <rect
          x="0"
          y="0"
          width="100"
          height="100"
          stroke="red"
          strokeWidth="3px"
          fill="none"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

Comment: your viewBox is 100 x 100 but the space you're putting it in is 200 x 150. How are you expecting to fill the shape completely and preserve the aspect ratio of your SVG. Something's got to give.

Comment: Specify `width` and `height` of svg as attributes (not styles), and remove `viewBox`: `<svg className="test-component-svg" width="200" height="150">`